# Python 3 error when running the print command

Tags: python, python3

All I wrote in the interpreter was as follows:

```
>>> print "Hello, World!"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "Hello, World!"
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How did I even get an error? All I tried to do was run a print command.

Comment: I've edited out your second question. If you still want the answer to that question, go ahead and ask it in a separate question post.

Comment: This is a basic programming in Python syntax question. It probably isn't appropriate for AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python3 print is a function:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

Check:
http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: And I now feel like a nooblet. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Yeah. This is going to cause me a shedload of issues when Ubuntu (or me on my own) finally moves to Python 3.x

Comment: The "2to3" tool should easily fix this ones.

Answer (score 3):

One of the major changes in Python 3 is that `print` has become a function.  Try using:

```
print('Hello World')
```

That should work.

Answer (score 3):

Python 3 has changed `print` from being a statement to being a function. This is how you print "hello world" in Python 3:

```
print("Hello world")
```

I recommend taking a look at [What's new in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html), this issue is the first one mentioned on the list.

I also recommend asking any programming questions on StackOverflow, in my experience, they are welcoming to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers have already covered this, but you should do `print("Hello World")` instead. The reason why it's been [changed](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html) in python 3 is to allow keyword arguments such as `end` (to change the default newline end`) among others.

Example:

```
print("Hello World", end="") # will print an empty character at the end, not a newline
```