# Running Python 3.3.0 on Ubuntu 12.10 (print error)

Tags: 12.04, python3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python 3 error when running the print command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11312/python-3-1-error-when-running-the-print-command)

I installed Python 3.3.0 on Ubuntu 12.10(x64)and when I type print 'hello world' it brings syntax error.

But when I type that in Python 2.7.3 the code works.

Why is it happening?